# Adding a value to matplotlib matshow plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe called *grade* with *n* columns of independent variables and *n* rows of measurement. I want to visualize the correlation of each independent variables using this lines of code:

```
corr = grade.corr()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(28, 20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(corr,cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
fig.colorbar(cax)
ticks = np.arange(0,len(grade.columns),1)
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Peason r for XRF results')
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(grade.columns)
ax.set_yticklabels(grade.columns)
plt.show()
```

is there a way for me to add the value of correlation coefficient to each grid of the plot?

Comment: Use a [seaborn heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) with `annot=True`

Comment: If there is a way to do it with matplotlib, I would rather use matplotlib.

Comment: It is the same thing, but just more work and more places to make mistakes. Seaborn is a collection of auxiliary functions to easier create statistical plots. Seaborn is just a layer on top of matplotlib, and often matplotlib is used to make modifications and additions to seaborn plots.